# Asp.net openid examples with google account

Tags: asp.net, openid

I'm looking for specific asp.net examples to allowing signin to a site using google account but not really seeing any. I see lots of specs for openid and while I get the general idea and love it I just want some code that allows this to happen for google within .net but not seeing any. Any examples around that maybe I just haven't found?

I'm not really interested in learning the details. I get the jist and trust what I'm reading about it and agree its a good thing. I just want some .net code to implement this.